# How's the support of ARIA landmark roles of current AT's?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is adding `role="navigation"` to all `nav` elements on a webpage still a must in order to make the ARIA landmark role being supported by current AT's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is well supported with JAWS in IE9+, the `<nav>` element *does not* get an implicit landmark role in the current version of VoiceOver with Safari. It is also inconsistent with NVDA and Firefox, and entirely absent with NVDA and IE9. `role='navigation'` however is [almost universally supported](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/landmarks.html) across screen readers.

As it stands, if you want `<nav>` elements to be navigable as a landmark reliably across user agents, **use `<nav role='navigation'>`**.

Comment: @RyanB, Creating a new answer was appropriate and fair. Your response was incorrect, not just needing adjustment.